# MySQL log file disable

Tags: mysql, logging

My question is how to stop logs on mysql

```
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log i have commented already.
```

with slow queries too. But i have one more log file in /var/lib/mysql/hostname.log
with hostname I mean that for example I am on server called hulk so the log will be 
hulk.log and so on. In that log are all queries. So the log is growing really fast and also
is really big. So my question is how to disable this log ?

Comment: Why would you want to stop logging?  What happens if you need to track down some error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you would like to dynamically stop logging, login as `root@localhost` and run this:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';
```

That's it. No restart of mysql needed.

If you are not `root@localhost`, you will need to be logged in as a user with [**SUPER privilege**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super).

Comment: thx man it is works ;)

Comment: it doesn't disable error log for me !!!

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL  5.1.12+ add/change this in your `my.cnf`

```
general-log = 0
```

In MySQL  5.1.11- remove this in your `my.cnf`

```
log
```

or

```
log =
```

Source:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log

Comment: general-log = 0 works fine, but on master I cant do restart so I disable logs like RolandoMySQLDBA said. But on slaves I tries your way and is working also thx

Comment: In MySQL 5.5.49 , the entry is `general_log = 0`

Answer (score 0):

`vim /etc/my.cnf`

There are two lines you want to comment out:

```
log=...
log-error=...
```

Restart mysql by

`service mysql restart`

or

`service mysqld restart`

Logging will be turned off now. Reverse the process when you want to turn it back on (if you do...) :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would want to keep logs (or better yet, ship off to a log-aggregation service), and also apply [`logrotate`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) to the local log files.